# how to give navigation to website in anchor tag dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append a dynamically created link into a `<div>` with JavaScript, but the link isn't working.

```
$('#web').append('<a href="'+responseObj.me[i].webUrl+'" rel="external">'+responseObj.me[i].webUrl+'</a>');`
```

HTML code

```
<div id=web></div>
```

`responseObj.me[i].webUrl` is a JSON response from my server which contains `google.co.in`.

Comment: How does the output of `responseObj.me[i].webUrl` look like?

Comment: Does the `a` get appended? What were you expecting from it? Is the user supposed to click on it?

Comment: try to add 'http://' while adding href.

Comment: See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ad5h/) without http & with http [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ad5h/1/).

Comment: Ya. What does the response object look like? Have you tried just `console.log(JSON.stringify(responseObj.me[i], null, 4))` just to make sure it exists and see what its structure is, right?

Comment: @morkro output of responseObj.me[i].webUrl is google.co.in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely that your `responseObj.me[i].webUrl` is incorrect or `undefined`. I also noticed that you had a grave accent character at the end of you javascript paste. Was it accidental or does it exist in your code as well?

I created a jsfiddle here, you can see that it works (at least on jQuery 2.1.0 version)

http://jsfiddle.net/V49Fe/1/

HTML

```
<div id="web"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var string = "google.co.in";
$('#web').append('<a href="'+string+'" rel="external">'+string+'</a>');
```

If you mean that your link is not pointing to actual google.co.in url, that is because
you need to have `http://` in front of the url, like this:

```
$('#web').append('<a href="http://'+string+'" rel="external">'+string+'</a>');
```

Comment: see,that character was accidently pasted..its  not in code.but still i m not getting output. see for me this string contains value like string=google.co.in and its not getting navigated.its showing error like navaigation failed www/google.co.in

Comment: @user3855674: This answer explains that. It's because `google.co.in` is _not_ a web address. You forgot the `http://`. Without `http://`, it looks like a relative path from your current page.

Comment: thanks a lot...thanks for ur help...its working now...at the end of the day..u solved my problem